# Build a Node package using Typescript 1.5 and generate the declaration file

Tags: node.js, typescript, declaration

I am new to Javascript, Node and Typescript and trying hard to use them.

---

### TL;DR

- How do we properly build a node package using Typescript ?
- How do we properly build a declaration file matching the node package API in one nice file?

---

### Here is my story:

I would like to use Typescript to code a javascript library to a Node.js format. And, finally, I would like to generate the appropriate declaration file to make it available for future Typescript development. I use `gulp-typescript` to compile them all.

After hours of research and errors...

### Here is what I did:

**foo.ts**

```
export class Foo {
    private id: number;
    constructor() {
        this.id = 0;
    }
}
```

**impl.ts**

```
import foo = require('foo');

export function make(): boolean {
    var f = new foo.Foo();
    return true;
}
```

**main.ts**

```
declare module 'test' {
    export import impl = require('impl');
}

module.exports = {
    impl: require('impl')
};
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
  , ts = require('gulp-typescript');    

var TS_FILES = 'src/**/*.ts';    

gulp.task('default', ['build_node']);    

// Compile the node package from Typescript source code
gulp.task('build_node', function() {
  var project = ts.createProject({
    declarationFiles: true,
    emitDecoratorMetadata: true,
    module: 'commonjs',
    noEmitError: true,
    noImplicitAny: true,
    removeComments: true,
    target: 'ES5'
  });    

  var tsResult = gulp.src(TS_FILES)
  .pipe(ts(project));    

  tsResult.js
  .pipe(gulp.dest('build'));    

  tsResult.dts
  .pipe(gulp.dest('definition'));
});
```

### Here is what I've got:

- 3 declaration files:

**foo.d.ts**

```
export declare class Foo {
    private id;
    constructor();
}
```

**impl.d.ts**

```
export declare function make(): boolean;
```

**main.d.ts**

```
declare module 'test' {
    export import impl = require('impl');
}
```

- 3 javascript files:

`foo.js` and `impl.js` just look normal. And...

**main.js**

```
module.exports = {
    impl: require('impl')
};
```

I don't even know if it works or not, but for sure, it looks wrong to me... I mean I really think I messed up and that's not the right way to build a node package and have its declaration file.

**The reasons ?**

When I look at the DefinitelyTyped declaration file, most of them are in one file with every `export` declaration nicely included as follow:

```
declare module 'test' {
    export function make(): boolean;
    ...
}
```

And have a node package exposing its API a follow:

```
module.exports = {
    version: '1.0',
    impl: require('impl');
}
```

I read hundred of post, but nothing seems generate what I want.

Could you please explain to me:

- How do we properly build a node package using Typescript ?
- How do we properly build a declaration file matching the node package API in one nice file?

**Edit:** I am not using `export =` because I want to be able to declare and export several things in one file. Ex: Having a class, and constructor helper function in the same file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I achieve to build something that works

[project](https://github.com/data-avail/da-trader-net-rx)

- Build js lib separately as is.

  - Remove all `///<reference ...` tags from output
- Build type definition file from template

  - Build definition files as is
  - Concatenate them all in single file
  - Remove all `///<reference ...` tags and `import` from output
  - Insert output entry into template `index.tmpl.d.ts` file
  - Replace `declare export ...` to `export ...`

Answer (score 2):

There are *lots* of ways to do this as there is no *official* support yet. You can track the official support here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2338

However I use https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript#packagejson-support

Sample project on NPM: https://github.com/basarat/ts-npm-module

Sample project *using* the project from NPM: https://github.com/basarat/ts-npm-module-consume

Comment: Oh my... This is really troublesome... I think I will wait for an official support. Do you have any idea when it could come up ? NB: Since I asked for TS 1.5 and there's no offcial support, I will validate your answer.